# How do I make the object (ball) move after 5 seconds?

Tags: processing

I have the code for which the ball moves as soon as I run the code but I want it to move after 5 seconds.
I have written the code in Processing.
This is my code:

```
void setup(){
  size(640,450);
}

void draw() {
 background(155);
 ellipse(x, 100, 50, 50);
 x = x + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`millis()` will return the number of milliseconds since you started the program. You can try this:

```
int x = 0;

void setup(){
  size(640,450);
}

void draw() {
 background(155);
 ellipse(x, 100, 50, 50);
 if (millis() > 5000) {
   x = x + 1;
 }
}
```

And the ball will wait 5 seconds. Have fun!